# Model theory and dynamical system (open problems)

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, model-theory, open-problems

I am curious about the open problems which are between model theory and dynamical system. I mean the open problems that are interesting for both groups and there are some evidences showing there might be a nice interaction between model theory and dynamical systems. Thank you!

Any references would be appreciated!

Comment: Self-promotion: [here's](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353074/elementary-equivalence-between-n-mapsto-n1-and-its-inverse-on-the-stone-%c4%8cech) one dynamical open model-theoretic question.

Comment: Depending on what you mean by a "dynamical system", Vaught's conjecture might be the canonical example.

Comment: If by a "dynamical system" you mean a $\mathbf Z$-action, this is much more restricted. Otherwise, there are lots of problems and conjectures related to model-theoretic group actions (of type-definable groups or of automorphism groups).

Comment: I actually meant Z-action!

Comment: Not a $\Bbb Z$-action but here is an important one: let $\mathcal F$ be a Fraïssé class in a *finite* relational language $L$ and let $\Bbb F$ be its Fraïssé limit. Must $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb F)$ have a metrizable universal minimal flow? More generally in the last ~15 years there has been a lot of interest in this kind of questions following the pubblication of the Kechris-Pestov-Todorcevic correspondence