# $\Sigma^2_1$ and the Continuum Hypothesis

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals, infinite-combinatorics, continuum-hypothesis

This is a follow up to [Will Brian's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/353004/14094) to [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/353000/near-permutation-n-mapsto-n1-not-conjugate-to-its-inverse-on-the-stone-%C4%8Cech-r).  In particular, quoting Brian:

"In fact, Paul Larson has pointed out to me that the statement "$\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are conjugate" is a now very rare example of a $\Sigma^2_1$ statement about the real line whose status we do not know under ZFC+CH."

(A $\Sigma^2_1$ statement is one that can be expressed in the form $\exists A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\psi(A,r)$ where $r$ is a fixed real parameter and $\psi$ is a formula whose quantifiers range only over $\mathbb{R}$.)

How rare is "very rare"?  Are there any other known examples of $\Sigma^2_1$ statements concerning the real line whose status under CH (+ large cardinals) is unknown?  What are some other examples?

Comment: This should say ZFC+CH+large cardinals, or we get silly projective statements.

Comment: Thanks @AndrésE.Caicedo!

Comment: Well another example, though of the same kind, is the following: let $(p_n)$ and $(p'_n)$ be the increasing sequence of primes $=1$ mod $4$, resp. $=3$ mod $4$ (this precise choice doesn't matter), let $c$ be a permutation with one $p_n$-cycle for each $n$ and no other cycle, and similarly define $c'$. Are $c$ and $c'$ conjugate as self-homeomorphisms of the Stone-Cech remainder? I just guess it's unknown, I'm not sure anyone else ever thought about it.

Comment: As an outsider, I don't guess what's the meaning of "under CH+ large cardinals". Does it mean "*under CH, assuming the consistency of existence of some kind (what kind?) of large cardinal*"? or  *"under CH + existence of some kind (what kind??) of large cardinal"? is the [consistency of the?] existence of a strongly inaccessible cardinal enough to avoid the pathologies mentioned by Andrés? By the way I'd also like to see some "typical" illustrating examples of theorems of ZFC or ZFC+CH reducing to a $\Sigma_1^2$ statement.

Comment: This is all motivated by a result of Woodin that $\Sigma^2_1$ statements are absolute for set forcing between models of ZFC+CH+"enough large cardinals".  So if there are enough large cardinals around, there is a kind of "canonical" theory of ZFC+CH at the level of $\Sigma^2_1$.  The question of whether $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ are conjugate has the right complexity, but it is unknown what the answer is in the canonical theory. (Also, Andres is much more of an expert on this than I am, so he may be able to say more intelligent things here.)

Comment: And indeed, he has.  See 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108197/sets-of-reals-and-absoluteness/108200#108200

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Thanks for pointing that out. As you could probably guess, the error is mine, not Paul's. Todd, one answer to your question, which I also got from Paul Larson, is "there is a self-homeomorphism $\psi$ of $\omega^*$ that commutes with the shift map $\phi$ but is not a power of it." Like the example in YCor's comment, I'm not sure this should really qualify as an answer, because it seems a bit too close to the statement we started with. It would be nice to see an example that doesn't just ask about pathological automorphisms of $\mathcal P(\omega)/\mathrm{fin}$.